# One sample or two sample when comparing the same points over time

Tags: time-series, paired-data, pre-post-comparison

I have 425 sample points that have been classified according to land cover in two time periods. When comparing how percent land cover has changed over time, is this a one sample test (ie. because the same points are sampled), or a two sample test (ie. because two separate time periods)? I'm pretty sure that each time period should represent a separate sample and so a two sample approach should be used, but just want to check!

Answer (score 0):

You have *paired data*, the two observations of the same point constitutes a pair. The basic analysis here could be a paired t-test, see for instance [Paired t-test between different algorithms: Properties of paired t-test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/429785/paired-t-test-between-different-algorithms-properties-of-paired-t-test), or the same way with some other one-sample test applied to the differences.

But this assumes that the different pairs are independent, and it seems you have some kind of spatial data, so independence might not hold. So look also at maps of the differences, and other plots.